# Loading a clipped image into a new variable

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a top-down MMORPG, in JavaScript. As you can imagine, this requires a lot of sprite sheets, and herein lies the problem.

I can simply place the clipped version of a sprite sheet onto the canvas using the `canvas.drawImage` method. However, this must require more performance than simply loading the clipped version of the image into a new image object which I'd then place onto the canvas using the `canvas.drawImage` method, as I'd only have to clip it once.

Is this at all possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Take a look at https://spritejs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a sprite. Any "clipping" is a convenient illusion. **Loading** a clipped version adds more HTTP traffic which will certainly take more time than drawing canvas image, regardless of the image source, especially when you have the image on the client already.